# Nav menu not animating right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to sort out a vertical navigation bar that is fixed to the right hand of the screen, at the moment it shows ok, but what i want is that when the user clicks on one of the choices, the menu expands to the left. At the moment it does expand, but it doesn't work great, all the other menu options underneath close up and the new menu expanding expands underneath the choice selected, where as it should expand on top, hopefully you will get what i mean by this jsfiddle i created. My version uses images instead of the colour, but hopefully it will be the same either way

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EfbvA/6/)

Just to let you know its not a case of just expanding the menu option, the bit that slides across is a new image, so i think it will need to be a new div etc..

Anyway, thankyou very much for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to A.K's answer, I mocked this up quick for you. It's not exactly as you need it, as I'm at work, but it shows you this can be done with purely CSS3.

http://jsfiddle.net/NDqdt/2/

EDIT: Ok, I got bored, here you are - fully functioning: http://jsfiddle.net/NDqdt/4/